# ¿Por qué desaparecen las cards del DOM cuando el usuario continúa introduciendo letras en el input de este buscador en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, funciones, dom, filtro, buscador

En este simulador de compras de productos alimenticios, existe un problema y es que cuando el usuario utiliza el buscador y va introduciendo letras en él, a medida que esto sucede van desapareciendo las cards generadas en el DOM. He probado varias cosas y quizás el problema esté en la función filtrar en alguna de las dos líneas donde implemento el toLowerCase, pero no logro como hallar la causa y su solución

```js
    // Declaro las variables
    let container = document.getElementById('c9__container');
    let buscador = document.getElementById('c9__input');
    let btn = document.getElementById('c9__btn');
    let pedido = document.getElementById('pedido')
    
    // STOCK
    const stocks = [{
        id: 1,
        nombre: "Papas",
        precio: 240,
        tipo: "papas",
        img: './assets/papas.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nombre: "Hamburguesa",
        precio: 440,
        tipo: "hamburguesas",
        img: './assets/burger.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        nombre: "MediaLuna y Cafe",
        precio: 150,
        tipo: "medialunas",
        img: './assets/medialunasycafe.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        nombre: "Empanadas",
        precio: 720,
        tipo: "empanadas",
        img: './assets/empanadas.jpg'
    },
    ];
    
    
    const carrito = []
    
    
    "use strict"
    let botones = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-compra');
    
    for (const boton of botones) {
        boton.addEventListener('click', comprarProducto)
    }
    
    
    // Creación de cards
    function crearCards(array) {
    
        array.forEach(elemento => {
            let tarjeta = document.createElement('div');
            tarjeta.classList.add('c9__card');
            tarjeta.innerHTML = `
                                    <img src="${elemento.img}" alt="">
                                    <h1>${elemento.nombre}</h1>
                                    <p><b><i>$${elemento.precio}</i></b></p>
                                    <a href="#" id='${elemento.id}' class="btn-compra">Sumar al carrito</a>
                                `
    
            container.appendChild(tarjeta);
        })
    }
    crearCards(stocks)
    
    
    // Filtrado de los productos 
    function filtrar() {
        container.innerHTML = '';
        let texto = buscador.value.toLowerCase();
    
        for (const stock of stocks) {
            let nombre = stock.nombre.toLowerCase();
            if (nombre.indexOf(texto) !== -1) {
                container.innerHTML += `<div class="c9__card">
                                            <img src="${stock.img}" alt="">
                                            <h1>${stock.nombre}</h1>
                                            <p><b><i>$${stock.precio}</i></b></p>
                                            <a href="#" id='${stock.id}' class="btn-compra">Sumar al carrito</a>
                                        </div>`
            }
        }
        if (container.innerHTML === '') {
            container.innerHTML += `<div class="c9__card"><p>Producto no encontrado</p></div>`
        }
    }
    
    buscador.addEventListener('keyup', filtrar)
    
    // 
    function comprarProducto(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let encontrado = stocks.find(x => x.id == e.target.id)
        carrito.push(encontrado)
        sumarCarrito(carrito)
    }
    
    // Contador de productos en el carrito
    function sumarCarrito(carrito) {
        let contador = document.getElementById('contador');
        contador.innerText = carrito.length
    }
    
    // Aparecen los iconos
    let marca = document.querySelector('.c9__container')
    marca.onclick = () => {
        let iconos = document.getElementById('iconos')
        iconos.classList.add('mostrar')
    }
    
    // Desaparición de los iconos y vaciar carrito
    let borrar = document.getElementById('tacho');
    
    borrar.addEventListener('click', function () {
        iconos.classList.remove('mostrar')
        while (carrito.length > 0) {
            carrito.pop();
        }
        total = 0
    })
    
    // Suma de todo el carrito
    let comprar = document.getElementById('comprar')
    let total = 0;
    comprar.addEventListener('click', function comprar() {
        for (let i = 0; i < carrito.length; i++) {
            total = total + carrito[i].precio;
        }
    })
    
    // Popup Enviar compra
    comprar.addEventListener('click', function togglePopup() {
        document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    })
    
    comprar.addEventListener('click', function mostrarPedido() {
        for (const producto of carrito) {
            let lista = document.createElement('li');
            lista.innerHTML += `1x ..... <strong>${producto.nombre}</strong> $${producto.precio}`
            document.getElementById('listaCarrito').appendChild(lista)
        }
    })
```

```html
        <!-- ========== Script FontAwesome ========== -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6050990e90.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- ========== Css ========== -->
   
    
        <h1 class="title">Fast Food Store</h1>
        <div class="c9__body">
            <div class="c9__buscador">
                <input class="c9__input" id="c9__input" type="text" placeholder="Busque el producto que desea">
                <i class="fas fa-search c9__lupa" id="c9__btn"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="iconos" id="iconos">
                <div class="changuito tacho" id="tacho">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="changuito carro">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart cart"></i>
                    <span class="contador" id="contador">0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="changuito comprar" id="comprar">
                    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="c9__container" id="c9__container"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="content" id="pedido">
                <h1>Su pedido:</h1>
                <ul id="listaCarrito">
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo que por qué? Pues obviamente porque lo que tecleas en buscar no coincide con ninguna card. Por eso desaparecen. Yo veo que funciona bien.

Comment: En el fragmento de código parece funcionar correctamente, mostrando solo los elementos que coinciden con la búsqueda.